# JMSSerializer intersection of grouped properties

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have entity as following:

```
class A
{
   /**
    * @JMS\Groups({"writable", "other"})
    */
   private $varA;

   /**
    * @JMS\Groups({"writable"})
    */
   private $varB;

   /**
    * @JMS\Groups({"other"})
    */
   private $varC;
}
```

I want to make serializer to generate output for properties that exists in BOTH groups so in simplier words I need an intersection of grouped properties.

```
$context = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(['writable' ,'other']);
$serializer->serialize(new A(), 'json', $context);
```

The code above should output only variable `$varA` because it has both groups defined.

How to achieve it? The only thing that comes to my mind is to extend GroupExclusionStategy that comes from JMSSerializer but maybe there's better way?

Comment: probably you want an union not an intersection, do you?

Comment: No I don't. Union is when variable can be either in group `writeble` and `other` and intersection is when it needs to be in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dag into the code of jms and I've found that setGroups uses GroupsExclusionStrategy but there are also different strategies and ExclusionStrategyInterface. So I've implemented this interface into my own

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Jms\Serializer;

use JMS\Serializer\Context;
use JMS\Serializer\Exclusion\ExclusionStrategyInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\PropertyMetadata;

/**
 * Class IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy
 * @package AppBundle\Jms
 */
class IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategyInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $groups;

    /**
     * IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy constructor.
     * @param array $groups
     */
    public function __construct(array $groups)
    {
        $this->setGroups($groups);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function shouldSkipProperty(PropertyMetadata $property, Context $navigatorContext)
    {
         if (is_array($this->groups) && is_array($property->groups)) {
            return !(!empty($this->groups) && array_intersect($this->groups, $property->groups) === $this->groups);
         }

         return false;
    }

    /**
     * Whether the class should be skipped.
     *
     * @param ClassMetadata $metadata
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function shouldSkipClass(ClassMetadata $metadata, Context $context)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $groups
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setGroups(array $groups)
    {
        $this->groups = $groups;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When serializing instead of using `setGroups` I've used

```
$intersectExclusionStrategy = new IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy($groups);
$serializationContext = SerializationContext::create();
$serializationContext->addExclusionStrategy($intersectExclusionStrategy);
```

Where `$groups` held values `['writable' ,'other']`.

It worked pretty well.

I've also created test for it if someone needed.

```
<?php
use AppBundle\Jms\Serializer\IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy;

class IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testShouldSkipPropertyGroups()
    {
        $intersectExclusionStrategy = new IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy(['group_a', 'group_b']);

        $propertyMetaData = $this->getMock('JMS\Serializer\Metadata\PropertyMetadata', [], [], '', false);
        $context = $this->getMock('JMS\Serializer\Context', [], [], '', false);

        $propertyMetaData->groups = ['group_a', 'group_b', 'group_c'];

        $this->assertNotTrue($intersectExclusionStrategy->shouldSkipProperty($propertyMetaData, $context));

        $propertyMetaData->groups = ['group_a', 'group_b'];

        $this->assertNotTrue($intersectExclusionStrategy->shouldSkipProperty($propertyMetaData, $context));

    }

    public function testShouldNotSkipPropertyGroups()
    {
        $intersectExclusionStrategy = new IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy(['group_a', 'group_b']);

        $propertyMetaData = $this->getMock('JMS\Serializer\Metadata\PropertyMetadata', [], [], '', false);
        $context = $this->getMock('JMS\Serializer\Context', [], [], '', false);

        $propertyMetaData->groups = ['group_a', 'group_c'];

        $this->assertTrue($intersectExclusionStrategy->shouldSkipProperty($propertyMetaData, $context));

        $propertyMetaData->groups = ['group_d', 'group_e'];

        $this->assertTrue($intersectExclusionStrategy->shouldSkipProperty($propertyMetaData, $context));

        $intersectExclusionStrategy = new IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy([]);

        $this->assertTrue($intersectExclusionStrategy->shouldSkipProperty($propertyMetaData, $context));
    }

    public function testShouldSkipClassReturnsFalse()
    {
        $intersectExclusionStrategy = new IntersectGroupsExclusionStrategy(['group_a', 'group_b']);

        $classMetaData = $this->getMock('JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata', [], [], '', false);
        $context = $this->getMock('JMS\Serializer\Context', [], [], '', false);

        $this->assertFalse($intersectExclusionStrategy->shouldSkipClass($classMetaData, $context));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a simple solution could be add another group name ("exclusive") to `$varA` property:

```
/**
 * @JMS\Groups({"writable", "other", "exclusive"})
 */
private $varA;
```

followed by:

```
$context = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups('exclusive');
```

but probably this is just a sample use-case. In the other way, should be created a `CustomGroupsExclusionStrategy()`.

---

By default `GroupsExclusionStrategy()` checks whether any property group is included into requested groups:

```
private function shouldSkipUsingGroups(PropertyMetadata $property, $groups)
{
    foreach ($property->groups as $group) {
        if (in_array($group, $groups)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

So, to do that you need change this one to:

```
private function shouldSkipUsingGroups(PropertyMetadata $property, $groups)
{
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        if (!in_array($group, $property->groups)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thus all requested group must be included into the property groups.

Solution:

> https://gist.github.com/yceruto/90b1ac46c8e33d51ec21079725949f77

I leave here an implementation by using a flag "strict" strategy:

```
$context = SerializationContext::create();
$context->addExclusionStrategy(
    new CustomGroupsExclusionStrategy(['writable', 'other'], true)
);

$json = $this->get('serializer')->serialize(new A(), 'json', $context);
```

Output:

```
{"varA":"foo"}
```

Comment: I'm aware of making `varAVarB` groups but it's dirty solution which I wanted to avoid. I know what GroupsExclusionStrategy does. I've done my class based on it. What I wasn't aware is that you can simply use `addExclusionStrategy` method on context and I've even looked for container changes in the bundle but this wasn't replacable by bundle. 

Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: Also the documentation is not very deep you need to often look into the code to understand how it works ;/